# Scala traits and name collision in abstract types

Tags: scala, traits, abstract-type

I'm trying define a trait `C` which extends some traits `A`,`B`,... All traits,`C`  and `A`,`B`,... implement a common trait `T`. Trait `C` is supposed to implement `T` by calling the implementations of  `T` in `A`,`B`,..:

```
trait T{
  def f()
}
trait A extends T{
  def f(){
    print("A")
  }
}
trait B extends T{
  def f(){
    print("B")
  }
}
```

The desired behavior of trait `C` is as follows:

```
val x=new A with B with C[A,B]{}
x.f()
// should produce output
A
B
```

Here my attempt to define trait C, which gave compilation errors:

```
trait C[A<:T,B<:T] extends T{
  self:A with B =>
  override def f(){
    // error: A does not name a parent class of trait C
    super[A].f()
    // error: B does not name a parent class of trait C
    super[B].f()
  }
}
```

I need to call within `C` methods `A.f()` and `B.f()`.
Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide an implementation inside of a trait but also ensure that subclasses implement the definition, it is possible to tell this the compiler with the `abstract override` combination:

```
trait T {
  def f()
}
trait A extends T {
  abstract override def f() {
    super.f()
    print("A")
  }
}
trait B extends T {
  abstract override def f() {
    super.f()
    print("B")
  }
}

trait C extends T {
  override def f() {
    // do your work here ...
  }
}

val x = new C with A with B
x.f()
```

To call the next implementation in the mixin-hierarchy you must add a `super.f()` call inside of the `abstract override` method call. Because such a super call requires an existing implementation the first thing you need to create is an instance of `C` that mixins `A` and `B`. If you mixin `C` in `A` or `B` the compiler will complain because the mixin-hierarchy is executed from left to right, thus the implementation of `C` can not be seen.